# How to get css animation to include line breaks?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

HERE IS THE ORIGINAL CODE --

```css
h1 { 
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
    width: 18ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
    white-space: pre;
    animation: caret .5s step-end infinite alternate,
             type 5s steps(18, end)
}



@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }

}
@keyframes caret { 
  50% { 
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
}
@use postcss-preset-env {
  stage: 0;
  autoprefixer: {
    grid: true;
  }
  browsers: [
    "last 1 Chrome versions",
    "last 1 Firefox versions",
    "last 1 Safari versions",
    "last 1 Edge versions"
  ]
}
```

```html
<h1>Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</h1>
```

EDIT -- Here is code that was made later, that is posted here both to help people find a solution and to ask a clarifying question, which is in the comments!

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 1.0;
}

h1 div {
  font-family: San Francisco, monospace;
  box-shadow: 1em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  width: var(--width);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: pre;
  animation: caret .5s step-end infinite alternate,
  type 5s steps(var(--length), end);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(5s * (var(--n) - 1));
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
}

h1 div:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
  --length: 17;
  --width: 17ch;
  --end: transparent;
}

h1 div:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
  --length: 7;
  --width: 7ch;
  --end: transparent;
}

h1 div:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
  --length: 7;
  --width: 7ch;
  --end: transparent;
}
h1 div:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
  --length: 7;
  --width: 7ch;
  --end: #05ffa3;
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 var(--end);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div>David F. Hamilton</div>
  <div>Coder.</div>
  <div>Editor.</div>
  <div>Critic.</div>
</h1>
```

--AND here was the original post!

I am having immense trouble with a small CSS thing (CSS is NOT my best language, so any help is appreciated).

So, this is meant to animate a header image --

```
    h1 { 
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
    width: 18ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
    white-space: pre;
    animation: caret .5s step-end infinite alternate,
             type 5s steps(18, end)
}



@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }

}
@keyframes caret { 
  50% { 
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
}
@use postcss-preset-env {
  stage: 0;
  autoprefixer: {
    grid: true;
  }
  browsers: [
    "last 1 Chrome versions",
    "last 1 Firefox versions",
    "last 1 Safari versions",
    "last 1 Edge versions"
  ]
}
```

The HTML would look something like this

```
<h1>Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</h1>
```

The problem is that rather than having the caret (which looks essentially like the current character one is typing) animates all three lines simultaniously, like this:

[where I'm at currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwoxN.png)

when it should animate a line at a time, looking like this (except across three lines, like the image before this):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SajGj.png)

tldr; this is supposed to look like someone typing three seperate lines, one after another, instead it looks broken and like someone is typing three lines simultaneously with one MASSIVE cursor! any help is appreciated. i am a css noob. :)

Comment: Could you put a working snippet into the question so we can try it for ourselves. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The method for showing the caret used here is to paint it, as a box-shadow, to the right of the element.

The element grows in 18 equal steps through an animation and so it looks as though the 'caret' is just ahead of the last character. (Or it would if the characters were monospaced - as in a typewriter).

It is possible to construct a CSS animation which will use this method to show the caret and gradually reveal the characters. It requires that each line be in its own element and that the number of characters in each line is known in advance. I suspect that in a general/real situation one would use a bit of JS to construct the animation, though once it were set going it would not need further JS.

This snippet still has some of the drawbacks of the original, the line length is fixed at 18 characters. (To have different length lines one would delay each animation by the sum of the times to do the previous ones.) I did not find the blinking of the caret very convincing so that is commented out but could of course be worked on to take account of the fixed width characters but variable width lines.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h1 div {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  box-shadow: 1em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  width: 18ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: pre;
  animation: /*caret .5s step-end infinite alternate,*/
  type 5s steps(18, end);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(5s * (var(--n) - 1));
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
}

h1 div:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

h1 div:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

h1 div:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div>Line 2</div>
  <div>Line 3</div>
</h1>
```

UPDATE: it is required that the flashing caret remain at the end of the last line. This snippet reinstates the caret (the box shadow) with a separate animation but ensures that it disappear at the end of a line and that it takes the same time across the line as the width-changing animation (10 * 0.5s) but gives the last line (the last child) an infinite rendering of the caret animation.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h1 div {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  rbox-shadow: 1em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  width: 18ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: pre;
  animation: caret .5s 10 linear, type 5s steps(18, end);
  animation-fill-mode: none, forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(5s * (var(--n) - 1)), calc(5s * (var(--n) - 1));
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
}

h1 div:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

h1 div:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

h1 div:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}
h1 div:last-child {
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, 1; /* keep caret visible and blinking at the end */
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
/* depends exactly what effect the 'caret' is to give as to how to time and step this */
  0% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  }
  49.9% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
  99.9% {  
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 transparent;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: .6em 0 0 #05ffa3;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div>Line 2</div>
  <div>Line 3</div>
</h1>
```

Note: if this were to be implemented in production then using CSS variables and calcs for the various timings and iteration counts would be useful as more easy to maintain than the built-in quantities we have here.

Also please be aware some people (e.g. epilepsy sufferers) could find continuous flashing problematic.

Comment: You are a godsend! A saint!

I have a brief question-- I've added an edit to my post showing what I've done with your code, to make it work a bit better for my specific interested. On my original code, the cursor continued its blinking animation infinitely, but on yours, even with my modifications that make it stay, its own animation stops, which is -- i think -- a bit less fun. Do you know what was changed that made this happen?

Comment: I'll have a look. I think the trick will be to reinstate the separate caret animation but make it infinite on the last line. It can be quite disturbing for some people to have something constantly flashing so you may want to give the user the option of removing it in a production system, or let it blink just for a bit longer then stop.